# Id should be similar but it isnt can someone explain me why

Tags: python

the id of the object before and after should be same but its not happening. can someone explain me why a new object is being made.

```
L = [1, 2, 3]    
print(id(L))
L = L + [4]
print(id(L))
```

both id's are that are being printed is different shouldn't it be the same its a mutable object. but when i use the append method of list to add 4 then the id is same

Comment: "shouldn't it be the same its a mutable object" no, because `+` returns a new list as the concatenation of its operands when the operands are lists.

Answer (score 1):

While lists are mutable, that doesn't mean that all operations involving them mutate the list in place. In your example, you're doing `L + [4]` to concatenate two lists. The `list.__add__` method that gets invoked to implement that creates a new list, rather than modifying `L`. You're binding the old name `L` to the new list, so the value you get from `id(L)` changes.

If you want to mutate `L` while adding a value onto the end, there are several ways you can do it. `L.append(4)` is the obvious pick if you have just a single item to add. `L.extend([4])` or the nearly synonymous `L += [4]` can work if the second list has more items in it than one.

Note that sometimes creating a new list will be what you want to do! If want to keep an unmodified reference to the old list, it may be desirable to create a new list with most of its contents at the same time you add new values. While you could copy the list then use one of the in place methods I mentioned above, you can also just use `+` to copy and add values to the list at the same time (just bind the result to a new name):

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
M = L + [4]  # this is more convenient than M = list(L); M.append(4)
print(L) # unchanged, still [1, 2, 3]
print(M) # new list [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanku so much for such a detailed and explained answer

Answer (score 0):

> its a mutable object

yes, you can change the value *without* creating a new object. But with the `+`, you are creating a new object.
To mute a mutable value, use methods (such as `append`) or set items (`a[0] = ...`).   As soon as you have `L=`, the object formerly referenced by `L` is lost (if it doesn't have any other references) and `L` gets a new value.

This makes sense because, in fact, with `L = L+[0]`, you are saying "calculate the value of `L+[0]` and assign it to L" not "add [0] to L".